# Django REST Framework - Additional field in ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In my ModelSerializer, I want to add required field `re_password`.

I want to use it during creating User model to check if `re_password` equals `password` field.

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        re_password = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False, write_only=True)
        fields = ('email','password')

    def validate_password(self, password):
        password, re_password = itemgetter('password', 're_password')(self.initial_data)

        if not password == re_password:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Passwords must be the same.')
```

My problem is that when I add `re_password` to fields I get error:

```
Field name `re_password` is not valid for model `User`.
```

(which is obvious in this case)

But if I don't, serializer don't see my additional field.

My goal, is to get following error, when there is no `re_password` field in POST request:

```
"re_password": [
    "This field is required."
]
```

I know that I can write code to check it, but maybe there is a way for a serializer to do it?

Comment: Try put this line out of Meta, but in the same level of Meta: re_password = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False, write_only=True)

Answer (score 0):

`required` is default `True`. `allow_blank` is default `False` [CharField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield)

Try this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    re_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password', 're_password']
```